# Comparing three posterior distributions

Tags: bayesian, mean, credible-interval

I estimated a variable for three different species and have a posterior distribution of 4000 estimates for each species. Now I want to know if the distribution between species differs significantly. How do I do this?

I have displayed the mean and 95% credible interval for each three species and would like to indicate if differences are significant.

Comment: One approach would be pairwise comparisons: for each pair, subtract the 4,000 posterior samples (what you're calling "estimates") from one group from the other. Then, compute a 95% credible interval (maybe using a quantile function) and see if the interval contains 0. If you want, you can adjust for multiple comparisons. But personally, I would rather just see side-by-side boxplots of the draws than a formal significance test (though I understand it may be necessary).

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean with adjust for multiple comparisons? I guess you mean I just do the pairwise comparison (species1 - species 2; species 2 - species 3 etc) manually for each combination?

Comment: I do mean that "[you] should just do the pairwise comparison (species1 - species 2; species 2 - species 3 etc)" (notice that etc is standing in for only 1 term, the 1-3 one). But when I said "adjust for multiple comparison", I meant what they're talking about here: https://www.nature.com/articles/nbt1209-1135 In our case, we could simply do a 98.3% interval instead (but it's not a huge deal in this case, and the average Bayesian would be unlikely to do this).

Comment: Are these posterior distributions independent or not?

Comment: Yes, they are independent.

Comment: One more question: how do I report on this? I am used to report test statistic, df and p-values the frequentist way.

Comment: *"distribution of 4000 estimates "* could you explain this a little bit more.

Comment: If u have 2 distributions u can see which distributions are closer and which are farther using KL divergence.

Answer (score 1):

Statistical significance expresses observed effects or differences in terms of probabilities. They are an expression of the relative [precision](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) of an experiment.

Given two posterior distributions: if they are independent, then you can compute the convolution of the distributions, and that is the distribution of the difference. Using that distribution of the difference you can express the significance for the difference.

For multiple comparisons at once, you could compute a highest density region for the joint distribution and check whether any of the lines $x=y, x=z, y=z$ are crossing the boundary.

The second method will result in a larger 'p-value', because it will count not all cases for some given $\Delta_{x-y}=x-y$. in general, there is no single way to express significance.

Comment: The second method will result in a larger p-value, because it will count not all cases for some given $\Delta_{x-y}=x-y$.